# Make something have a 1 percent chance of happening in Unity/C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want a rare object in my game to spawn 1 out of 100 times. This is my code:

```
int random = Random.Range(0, 99);

if (random < 1)
{
    //rare gameobject spawns
}
else
{
    //common gameobject spawns
}
```

This makes sense to me but it doesn´t seem to work correctly. I have seen this rare gameobject about 1 in 20-30 times. Why does it happen so often?

Comment: Have you *measured* that "1 in 20-30" or is it just an estimate? I'd start off by logging actual stats. The code looks reasonable to me.

Comment: You can test this in a loop running it thousands of times and logging the results.

Comment: what is your sample size?

Comment: If you literally want it to spawn 1 in 100 times, use a counter and only spawn it when the counter hits 100.

Comment: If you want 1%, you should be using 100 as the upper bound since it's exclusive. `Random.Range(0, 100)` will return a number that's 0 at the lowest and 99 at the highest.

Comment: What kind of sample set have you tested with? Random output can tend to only actually have a distribution that matches up with its input probabilities in large sample sets. You could also start with a much rarer probability but gradually increase it upon every spawn of a non-rare object until the probability approaches 1 and then reset after a rare object spawn.

Comment: @itsme86: No, it's inclusive according to [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) - but as it's returning float values, the range does still want to be (0, 100).

Comment: This is how random works, its about luck. If you're seeing the gameobject 30% of the time like you said, you're simply that lucky. Imagine how a dice works, you want to get 3 rolls of 6, sometimes you're lucky and you roll 3 sixes in a row, other times you don't get any six at all.

Comment: @DaisyShipton No, according to the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) it's exclusive. If you pass floats to the method then it's inclusive, but since OP is passing ints, it's exclusive.

Comment: @SwiftingDuster: Over a *small* number of calls, that would make sense - but if the OP is seeing "1 in 20-30" over a reasonably large set of calls, there's something else going on. That's why I've asked about measurement to start with.

Comment: @itsme86: I do apologise - I *looked* for a `Range(int, int)` overload, but couldn't see one for some reason. I can see it now.

Comment: This is almost certainly a sample size problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that is that making things really random is quite a diffucult task for a computer. There is lot of [literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) on generating random and pseudo-random values and I'm not an expert in this subject, but the basic idea consists of taking an occurring and continually changing value on your system (e.g. the time) and modify it in order to receive a "random" value.

When you won't receive values that fit your purpose (in your case, the event occurs too often), try to use another (equals more complex) algorithm.

Edit: Test your function isolated by surrounding it with some kind of test function like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomTest : MonoBehaviour
{    
    private const int TestRuns = 1000000;
    private const int Probability = 1;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        int hits = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < TestRuns; i++)
        {
            int randomValue = Random.Range(0, 100);
            if (randomValue < Probability)
            {
                hits++;
            }
        }

        float probability = (float) hits / TestRuns * 100;

        Debug.Log("Outcome: " + probability.ToString("f4") + " %");
    }
}
```

For me, the values are quite close to what is expected and should (didn't calculate it) lay within the standard distribution:

`Outcome: 0.9984 %`

Comment: Do you really think it's an issue with `Random` and not with the test sample size?

Comment: OP is not using Unity's Random API

Comment: @RufusL I think it could relate to issues when and by which function this method is called. Test sample size could be an issue but it should not have such a big impact (factor of 30).

Comment: Changing the seed will influence the output sequence but it won't change the behavior of the generator in terms of duplicates or probabilities significantly unless the sample size is small enough for just getting any new sequence to have a large effect on the output frequencies. The seed is not the issue here.

Comment: @RufusL Oops my bad. I apologize to both. I though OP was using  `Random.Next`. Ignore that comment.

Comment: @S.C. Yep, you're right. My bad! Would be nice to know in which context the random function is called.